# Junit test case for Camel REST API

Tags: java, junit, apache-camel

I am trying to write test case for Camel application where I have exposed REST API with POST method, can anyone let me know how can I test my API with JUnit in camel.
Below is my camel-context.xml code, have used application.properties to get the dynamic values and running the application with Springboot.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans          https://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd                 http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring https://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring.xsd">
    
    <bean id="requestprocessor" class="com.rue21.RequestProcessor" />
    <!-- Camel context where it has multiple routes and flow starts -->
    <camelContext id="KiboIntegrationCamelContext"
        xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring" streamCache="true">
        <!-- Setting up redeliverypolicy for DB retrials -->
        <redeliveryPolicyProfile
            id="kiboRedeliveryPolicy" maximumRedeliveries="{{kibo.retry.count}}"
            redeliveryDelay="{{kibo.retry.delay}}" retryAttemptedLogLevel="WARN" />

        <restConfiguration component="servlet"
            enableCORS="true" />
        <rest id=" RestCallForKiboServices ">
            <post id="PostCallForKiboAPI" uri="/rest/v1/kibo-api-post-call"
                produces="application/json">
                <route id="PostCallForKiboAPIRoute">
                    <to id="SyncCalltoPostCallForKibo"
                        uri="direct:kibo-post-api-call" />
                </route>
            </post>
        </rest>
        <!-- Kibo POST API Call -->
        <route id="KiboPostAPICallRoute">
            <from id="SyncCallfromPostCallForKibo"
                uri="direct:kibo-post-api-call" />
            <to id="SyncCalltoSetBasicDataforPostCall"
                uri="direct:set-basic-data" />
            <setHeader id="SetHttpMethodforPostCall"
                name="CamelHttpMethod">
                <simple>POST</simple>
            </setHeader>
            <setProperty id="GetPayloadforPostCall" name="payload">
                <jsonpath>$..body</jsonpath>
            </setProperty>
            <setProperty id="GetQueryParamsforPostCall"
                name="queryParams">
                <jsonpath>$..queryParams</jsonpath>
            </setProperty>
            <bean id="JavaCalltoSetQueryParamsforPostCall"
                ref="requestprocessor" method="getQueryParams" />
            <setBody id="SetPayloadforPostCall">
                <simple>${exchangeProperty.payload}</simple>
            </setBody>
            <convertBodyTo id="ConvertPayloadtoStringforPostCall"
                type="java.lang.String" />
            <bean id="JavaCalltoTransformPayloadforPostCall"
                ref="requestprocessor" method="getPayload" />
            <setHeader id="SetHttpQueryHeaderforPostCall"
                name="Exchange.HTTP_QUERY">
                <simple>${exchangeProperty.queryParams}&amp;connectTimeout={{kibo.api.connectTimeout}}&amp;socketTimeout={{kibo.api.socketTimeout}}</simple>
            </setHeader>
            <log id="LogRequestforPostCall"
                message="Request to Kibo POST API : ${body}" />
            <toD id="CallKiboAPIforPostCall"
                uri="{{kibo.api.host}}/${exchangeProperty.kiboAPIPath}?bridgeEndpoint=true&amp;throwExceptionOnFailure=false" />
            <log id="LogResponseforPostCall"
                message="Response from Kibo POST API : ${body}" />
            <onException useOriginalMessage="true"
                redeliveryPolicyRef="kiboRedeliveryPolicy">
                <exception>java.lang.Exception</exception>
                <handled>
                    <constant>true</constant>
                </handled>
                <log loggingLevel="INFO"
                    message="Exception occurred while invoking Kibo POST API!!! Exception message : ${exception.message}" />
            </onException>
        </route>
        <!-- Set basic data to call KIBO API -->
        <route id="SetBasicDataSubRoute">
            <from id="SyncCalltoSetBasicData" uri="direct:set-basic-data" />
            <removeHeaders id="RemoveHeaders" pattern="*"
                excludePattern="Accept|Content-Type" />
            <setHeader id="SetContentTypeforAPICall"
                name="Content-Type">
                <simple>application/json</simple>
            </setHeader>
            <setProperty id="SetKiboAPIPathforAPICall"
                name="kiboAPIPath">
                <jsonpath resultType="java.lang.String">$.kiboAPIPath</jsonpath>
            </setProperty>
        </route>
    </camelContext>
</beans>
```

I tried with below Junit code but getting this error "java.lang.AssertionError: mock://stream:out Body of message: 0. Expected: <{"status": 400,"errorMessage": "Bad Request","additionalInfo": "Order 608 cannot fully appease the requested 0.2 amount. Total amount left to refund is 0.17","errorCode": 5003,"timestamp": "2021-10-25T08:35:28.677857Z"}> but was: <{"status":400,"errorMessage":"Bad Request","additionalInfo":"Order 608 cannot fully appease the requested 0.2 amount. Total amount left to refund is 0.17","errorCode":5003,"timestamp":"2021-10-25T12:15:08.106789Z"}>"

```
import org.apache.camel.CamelContext;
import org.apache.camel.ProducerTemplate;
import org.apache.camel.builder.AdviceWith;
import org.apache.camel.component.mock.MockEndpoint;
import org.apache.camel.test.junit4.CamelTestSupport;
import org.apache.camel.test.spring.junit5.CamelSpringBootTest;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

@SpringBootTest
@CamelSpringBootTest
public class OMSUtilsApplicationTest extends CamelTestSupport {

    @Autowired
    private CamelContext camelContext;

    @Autowired
    private ProducerTemplate producerTemplate;

    public static final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    @Test
    public void testKiboPostAPICallRoute() throws Exception {
        MockEndpoint mock = camelContext.getEndpoint("mock:stream:out", MockEndpoint.class);

        Object request = "{\"kiboAPIPath\": \"/api/v2/orderAppeasement/\",\"queryParams\": [{\"key\": \"orderID\",\"value\": \"608\"}],\"body\": {\"creditPayee\": \"MANUFACTURER\",\"creditAmount\": 0.2,\"creditDescription\": \"CREDIT SETTLEMENT\",\"userID\": \"8910928\"}}";

        Object response = "{\"status\": 400,\"errorMessage\": \"Bad Request\",\"additionalInfo\": \"Order 608 cannot fully appease the requested 0.2 amount. Total amount left to refund is 0.17\",\"errorCode\": 5003,\"timestamp\": \"2021-10-25T08:35:28.677857Z\"}";

        AdviceWith.adviceWith(camelContext, "KiboPostAPICallRoute",
                // intercepting an exchange on route
                r -> {
                    // replacing consumer with direct component
                    r.replaceFromWith("direct:start");
                    // mocking producer
                    r.mockEndpoints("stream*");
                });

        // setting expectations
        mock.expectedMessageCount(1);
        mock.expectedBodiesReceived(response);

        // invoking consumer
        producerTemplate.sendBody("direct:start", request);

        // asserting mock is satisfied
        mock.assertIsSatisfied();
    }
}
```

My actual response is as below.

```
{
    "status": 400,
    "errorMessage": "Bad Request",
    "additionalInfo": "Order 608 cannot fully appease the requested 0.2 amount. Total amount left to refund is 0.17",
    "errorCode": 5003,
    "timestamp": "2021-10-25T12:09:51.293107Z"
}
```

Comment: Did you try with [camel-test-spring](https://camel.apache.org/components/3.11.x/others/test-spring.html) or [camel-test-spring-junit5](https://camel.apache.org/components/3.11.x/others/test-spring-junit5.html)?

Comment: I have tried with camel-test-spring

Comment: Well what problems did you have with it? The question is quite broad as testing routes that use rest consumer endpoints is not all that different from testing any route in camel. You advice/mock the endpoints you need to advice/mock with `AdviceWithRouteBuilder` and `MockEndpoint`(s) then send the consumer endpoint i.e `direct:kibo-post-api-call` what you expect it to receive and assert that MockEndpoint(s) receive stuff you expect them to receive.

Comment: I have updated my question with the Junit code, let me know if I have missed anything and let me know how can I fetch the response json from file set on resources.

Comment: Check `FileUtils.readFileToString` from apache `commons-io/commons-io` for easy way to read files from resources folder.  Since you're using adviceWith its good practice to add @UseAdviceWith and start the context manually on each tests. You'll also need to weaveById or URI and replace `CallKiboAPIforPostCall` endpoint in adviceWith and make it return your response. Now it looks like its calling the real api. Unit tests should not call any external apis.